How do I migrate a list field to a taxonomy term reference field
I am trying to figure out how to migrate a text list field (field_department) in Drupal 7 to a taxonomy term reference field in Drupal 10 (field_team_department). This is what I'm working with right now in my node migration yml file:
field_team_department:
-
  plugin: sub_process
  source: field_department
  process:
    plugin: entity_generate
    source: value
    value_key: name
    entity_type: taxonomy_term
    bundle_key: vid
    bundle: team_department
-
  plugin: log

This is almost there. The taxonomy terms are created but the field on the node isn't populated. The debug messages are:
'field_team_department' value is 'Array ( [source] => principals ) '

The value is correct here but I can't figure out how to get the value out of that array.
Thanks for any help!

I got it to work with this:
field_team_department:
-
  plugin: skip_on_empty
  method: process
  source: field_department
  message: 'Row does not contain Department'
-
  plugin: array_pop
-
  plugin: entity_generate
  entity_type: taxonomy_term
  value_key: name
  bundle_key: vid
  bundle: team_department
  ignore_case: true

Using migrate debug on another site migration that had a working taxonomy/term migration helped me to figure this out. Migrate debug should be showing at taxonomy term id for that field, not a label, like this:
  "field_team_department" => array:1 [
    0 => "3"
  ]

The remaining problem I had is that it was using the key from the old list field to create the taxonomy term labels. I decided not to take the time to figure out how to use the label for the migration. Instead I added an original_key field to the taxonomy and manually changed the name field to what it should be, and copied the key into my new field. I only had about 12 taxonomy terms here so this was doable. Then my new migration yml looked like this:
field_team_department:
-
  plugin: skip_on_empty
  method: process
  source: field_department
  message: 'Row does not contain Department'
-
  plugin: array_pop
-
  plugin: entity_generate
  entity_type: taxonomy_term
  value_key: field_original_key
  bundle_key: vid
  bundle: team_department
  ignore_case: true

